# Setting nginx expire headers only for fonts

Tags: caching, nginx, fonts, static

In my nginx configuration, I have this location directive:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/myproject/myproject/static/;
    access_log off;
    expires 30m;
    break;
}
```

Now, I want to set the 'expires' to 1y only for files (within /static/) with extension .woff, woff2.
The problem is that the fonts files can be in many different subfolders of `/var/www/myproject/myproject/static/`

I have tried appending this other directive (after the other one)

```
location ~* \.(?:ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 1d;
    break;
}
```

But the fonts files are throwing a 404 error.

Any help?

Many thanks!

Comment: Add `root /var/www/myproject/myproject/;` inside the block and see if it helps

Comment: Inside the 2nd block you mean? 
Would be `root /var/www/myproject/myproject/;` or `root /var/www/myproject/myproject/static/;' ??

Comment: Yes inside the second block

Comment: Have you found a solution?